# Adding FFMPEG support to Chromium Portable on Windows without recompiling

Tags: google-chrome, ffmpeg, chromium

I am using Chromium portable on Windows recently.

I downloaded Chromium portable from chromium.org, finding it without FFMPEG support, which means playing media just not possible for some websites.

Is there a simple or a little complex hack or plugin or patches to make FFMPEG on Chromium portable from chromium.org work? Thanks.

Due to personal reasons I am not intended to use Google Chrome for some months, due to its automatic updates something like Windows Update, making me annoyed.

On Linux, I know there is a package called chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra, which makes FFMPEG support possible. But I do NOT find something similar on Windows.

Recompiling Chromium costs hours, and I just do not want to use some third-party Chromium releases due to security requests.